Put a radius around locations and identify other locations within that radius
Here is some code to reproduce a data.frame containing coordinates:
x <- c(611547.6411, 589547.6411, 611447.6411, 609847.6411, 606347.6411, 611447.6411, 613547.6411,642747.6411, 589647.6411, 606447.6411, 613547.6411, 640347.6411, 642847.6411, 612147.6411, 613847.6411, 640247.6411, 642947.6411, 584347.6411, 587747.6411, 606447.6411, 614247.6411, 640447.6411, 642747.6411, 584447.6411, 608647.6411, 612047.6411, 612747.6411,
613847.6411, 643147.6411, 583147.6411, 608747.6411, 611847.6411, 609647.6411, 610047.6411, 613747.6411, 586247.6411, 588647.6411, 643147.6411, 584347.6411, 606447.6411, 610147.6411, 613347.6411, 614647.6411, 586047.6411, 587247.6411, 611547.6411, 640347.6411, 643147.6411, 587147.6411, 583047.6411, 608747.6411, 612047.6411, 613947.6411, 587647.6411, 588547.6411, 586847.6411, 611247.6411, 643247.6411, 587247.6411, 590347.6411, 582947.6411, 608947.6411, 611847.6411, 613447.6411, 614647.6411, 585147.6411, 587647.6411, 588547.6411, 586947.6411, 611247.6411, 643047.6411, 587147.6411, 583947.6411, 587747.6411, 608547.6411, 611747.6411, 614047.6411, 585247.6411, 586247.6411, 588447.6411, 589147.6411, 611347.6411, 642447.6411, 586947.6411, 585847.6411, 587747.6411, 581447.6411, 612447.6411, 611947.6411, 600547.6411,
612047.6411, 610347.6411, 614147.6411, 582847.6411, 588547.6411, 589247.6411, 611247.6411, 638147.6411, 640547.6411, 642947.6411, 587047.6411, 585947.6411, 587647.6411, 600447.6411, 611347.6411, 612347.6411, 610347.6411, 587747.6411, 579747.6411, 583847.6411, 586847.6411, 588447.6411, 589347.6411, 643347.6411, 589347.6411, 586947.6411, 588247.6411, 588847.6411, 585847.6411, 590847.6411, 589447.6411, 590947.6411, 581347.6411, 611847.6411, 600647.6411, 610347.6411, 615947.6411, 613947.6411, 586347.6411, 579647.6411, 584047.6411, 586347.6411, 587747.6411, 587947.6411, 586547.6411, 587647.6411, 614047.6411, 643047.6411, 587947.6411, 585747.6411, 584947.6411, 600547.6411, 611947.6411, 606847.6411, 600847.6411, 612847.6411, 615747.6411, 620747.6411, 614047.6411, 632947.6411, 588147.6411, 579747.6411, 582747.6411)

y <- c(5272140.5728, 5271740.5728, 5271640.5728, 5267440.5728, 5271540.5728, 5272040.5728, 5272340.5728, 5268540.5728, 5271240.5728, 5271640.5728, 5272140.5728, 5272240.5728, 5272240.5728, 5277940.5728, 5278040.5728, 5278040.5728, 5266940.5728, 5267040.5728, 5267440.5728, 5268140.5728, 5268640.5728, 5271140.5728, 5271740.5728, 5271740.5728, 5271940.5728, 5272140.5728, 5272240.5728, 5272040.5728, 5272140.5728, 5272140.5728, 5272140.5728, 5272240.5728, 5272340.5728, 5277240.5728, 5278040.5728, 5268540.5728, 5271240.5728, 5271340.5728, 5272240.5728, 5271940.5728, 5271940.5728, 5272040.5728, 5272040.5728, 5272040.5728, 5272040.5728, 5272040.5728, 5272140.5728, 5272140.5728,
5272140.5728, 5272240.5728, 5272240.5728, 5277240.5728, 5278040.5728, 5278140.5728, 5278140.5728, 5265540.5728, 5266840.5728, 5266940.5728, 5267040.5728, 5268540.5728, 5272240.5728, 5272340.5728, 5272040.5728, 5272040.5728, 5277340.5728, 5278140.5728, 5278140.5728, 5265640.5728, 5266840.5728, 5267240.5728, 5268440.5728, 5271540.5728, 5272140.5728, 5271840.5728, 5271940.5728, 5271940.5728, 5271940.5728, 5272040.5728, 5272040.5728, 5272140.5728, 5272140.5728, 5272140.5728, 5272340.5728, 5277140.5728, 5277240.5728, 5277340.5728, 5277740.5728, 5277740.5728, 5278040.5728, 5278140.5728, 5278140.5728, 5278240.5728, 5278240.5728, 5264940.5728, 5265040.5728, 5265140.5728, 5266740.5728, 5266840.5728, 5266940.5728, 5267040.5728, 5267140.5728, 5267340.5728, 5267440.5728, 5268340.5728,
5271240.5728, 5271840.5728, 5271940.5728, 5272040.5728, 5272040.5728, 5272340.5728, 5271840.5728, 5271840.5728, 5272140.5728, 5272140.5728, 5272240.5728, 5272240.5728, 5272340.5728, 5274340.5728, 5274440.5728, 5274640.5728, 5285140.5728, 5285240.5728, 5277340.5728, 5277540.5728, 5277840.5728, 5278040.5728, 5278040.5728, 5278140.5728, 5278140.5728, 5265540.5728, 5265640.5728, 5266740.5728, 5266740.5728, 5266940.5728, 5268340.5728, 5268440.5728, 5271440.5728, 5271540.5728, 5271540.5728, 5271740.5728, 5272040.5728, 5272340.5728, 5271740.5728, 5272240.5728, 5272240.5728, 5274540.5728, 5275040.5728, 5275340.5728, 5284840.5728, 5284940.5728, 5284940.5728, 5285040.5728, 5285040.5728)

coordinates.df <- as.data.frame(cbind(x,y))

# add an ID column that might be helpful and rearrange the columns
coordinates.df$ID <- 1:nrow(coordinates.df)
coordinates.df <- coordinates.df[c(3,1:2)]

X and Y coordinates are included. They correspond to projected coordinates in meters. Each row represents a location provided with an ID.
Now there are two things that should be done:

put a radius of 500 m around each of the locations
check if there are intersections between the resulting circles and display these cases

The goal is to have as much locations as possible without intersections at the end. Locations that lie within a circle are supposed to be removed. Lower location IDs are to be preferred. This means for example that if ID2 and ID14 intersect, ID14 shall be removed.
EDIT after the answer below from VinceGreg.
After performing the steps, the resulting plot from this
# Graphical
df_sf %>% st_buffer( dist = 500)  %>% 
  ggplot()  + geom_sf()+ geom_sf(data= df_sf2)

looks like this:

using
# Graphical
df_sf2 %>% st_buffer( dist = 500)  %>% 
  ggplot()  + geom_sf()+ geom_sf(data= df_sf2)

leads to this:

In both cases (I think the second one is the proper one with df_sf2) there are still some overlaps/intersections between some circles visible.

Hello. Are you sure that coordinates are lat/lon which should be decimal degrees ? It looks more projected coordinates in meters. It is important to generate buffers. I'm lost with your last line. Are those coordinates randomly drawn and you want an iterative process to eliminate points that are too close ? In this case no need to compute buffers but instead distances between points would suffice to filter out points.

Thanks Billy34 for the hints. You are right, these are projected coordinates. I have clarified this in the question. They are not randomly drawn, all of them fullfill certain conditions. But one constrain is that each of these locations should have a "free" radius of 500 m around them.

Are you still looking for a solution?

@Carl: At the moment I am trying to transfer the solution of VinceGreg to my actual dataset. It seems to work with the example data I provided. If you have another solution please feel free to provide.

Second attempt
I used a while loop to remove one of the closest point of the distance matrice at every iteration; until a distance of 1000m is observed. That way, two circles of 500.001 m of radius won't touch. My PC took 2 seconds for this dataset.
If 3 or more points are close togheter, the closest pair is selectionned; and the highest ID is removed. The process is then repeated.
library(sf)
library(tidyverse)

x <- c(611547.6411, 589547.6411, 611447.6411, 609847.6411, 606347.6411, 611447.6411, 613547.6411,642747.6411, 589647.6411, 606447.6411, 613547.6411, 640347.6411, 642847.6411, 612147.6411, 613847.6411, 640247.6411, 642947.6411, 584347.6411, 587747.6411, 606447.6411, 614247.6411, 640447.6411, 642747.6411, 584447.6411, 608647.6411, 612047.6411, 612747.6411,
       613847.6411, 643147.6411, 583147.6411, 608747.6411, 611847.6411, 609647.6411, 610047.6411, 613747.6411, 586247.6411, 588647.6411, 643147.6411, 584347.6411, 606447.6411, 610147.6411, 613347.6411, 614647.6411, 586047.6411, 587247.6411, 611547.6411, 640347.6411, 643147.6411, 587147.6411, 583047.6411, 608747.6411, 612047.6411, 613947.6411, 587647.6411, 588547.6411, 586847.6411, 611247.6411, 643247.6411, 587247.6411, 590347.6411, 582947.6411, 608947.6411, 611847.6411, 613447.6411, 614647.6411, 585147.6411, 587647.6411, 588547.6411, 586947.6411, 611247.6411, 643047.6411, 587147.6411, 583947.6411, 587747.6411, 608547.6411, 611747.6411, 614047.6411, 585247.6411, 586247.6411, 588447.6411, 589147.6411, 611347.6411, 642447.6411, 586947.6411, 585847.6411, 587747.6411, 581447.6411, 612447.6411, 611947.6411, 600547.6411,
       612047.6411, 610347.6411, 614147.6411, 582847.6411, 588547.6411, 589247.6411, 611247.6411, 638147.6411, 640547.6411, 642947.6411, 587047.6411, 585947.6411, 587647.6411, 600447.6411, 611347.6411, 612347.6411, 610347.6411, 587747.6411, 579747.6411, 583847.6411, 586847.6411, 588447.6411, 589347.6411, 643347.6411, 589347.6411, 586947.6411, 588247.6411, 588847.6411, 585847.6411, 590847.6411, 589447.6411, 590947.6411, 581347.6411, 611847.6411, 600647.6411, 610347.6411, 615947.6411, 613947.6411, 586347.6411, 579647.6411, 584047.6411, 586347.6411, 587747.6411, 587947.6411, 586547.6411, 587647.6411, 614047.6411, 643047.6411, 587947.6411, 585747.6411, 584947.6411, 600547.6411, 611947.6411, 606847.6411, 600847.6411, 612847.6411, 615747.6411, 620747.6411, 614047.6411, 632947.6411, 588147.6411, 579747.6411, 582747.6411)

y <- c(5272140.5728, 5271740.5728, 5271640.5728, 5267440.5728, 5271540.5728, 5272040.5728, 5272340.5728, 5268540.5728, 5271240.5728, 5271640.5728, 5272140.5728, 5272240.5728, 5272240.5728, 5277940.5728, 5278040.5728, 5278040.5728, 5266940.5728, 5267040.5728, 5267440.5728, 5268140.5728, 5268640.5728, 5271140.5728, 5271740.5728, 5271740.5728, 5271940.5728, 5272140.5728, 5272240.5728, 5272040.5728, 5272140.5728, 5272140.5728, 5272140.5728, 5272240.5728, 5272340.5728, 5277240.5728, 5278040.5728, 5268540.5728, 5271240.5728, 5271340.5728, 5272240.5728, 5271940.5728, 5271940.5728, 5272040.5728, 5272040.5728, 5272040.5728, 5272040.5728, 5272040.5728, 5272140.5728, 5272140.5728,
       5272140.5728, 5272240.5728, 5272240.5728, 5277240.5728, 5278040.5728, 5278140.5728, 5278140.5728, 5265540.5728, 5266840.5728, 5266940.5728, 5267040.5728, 5268540.5728, 5272240.5728, 5272340.5728, 5272040.5728, 5272040.5728, 5277340.5728, 5278140.5728, 5278140.5728, 5265640.5728, 5266840.5728, 5267240.5728, 5268440.5728, 5271540.5728, 5272140.5728, 5271840.5728, 5271940.5728, 5271940.5728, 5271940.5728, 5272040.5728, 5272040.5728, 5272140.5728, 5272140.5728, 5272140.5728, 5272340.5728, 5277140.5728, 5277240.5728, 5277340.5728, 5277740.5728, 5277740.5728, 5278040.5728, 5278140.5728, 5278140.5728, 5278240.5728, 5278240.5728, 5264940.5728, 5265040.5728, 5265140.5728, 5266740.5728, 5266840.5728, 5266940.5728, 5267040.5728, 5267140.5728, 5267340.5728, 5267440.5728, 5268340.5728,
       5271240.5728, 5271840.5728, 5271940.5728, 5272040.5728, 5272040.5728, 5272340.5728, 5271840.5728, 5271840.5728, 5272140.5728, 5272140.5728, 5272240.5728, 5272240.5728, 5272340.5728, 5274340.5728, 5274440.5728, 5274640.5728, 5285140.5728, 5285240.5728, 5277340.5728, 5277540.5728, 5277840.5728, 5278040.5728, 5278040.5728, 5278140.5728, 5278140.5728, 5265540.5728, 5265640.5728, 5266740.5728, 5266740.5728, 5266940.5728, 5268340.5728, 5268440.5728, 5271440.5728, 5271540.5728, 5271540.5728, 5271740.5728, 5272040.5728, 5272340.5728, 5271740.5728, 5272240.5728, 5272240.5728, 5274540.5728, 5275040.5728, 5275340.5728, 5284840.5728, 5284940.5728, 5284940.5728, 5285040.5728, 5285040.5728)

coordinates.df <- as.data.frame(cbind(x,y))

# add an ID column that might be helpful and rearrange the columns
coordinates.df$ID <- 1:nrow(coordinates.df)
coordinates.df <- coordinates.df[c(3,1:2)]

# Making a sf object
df_sf = coordinates.df %>% st_as_sf(coords=c("x","y"), remove= FALSE)# %>% 

min_dist = 1

while(min_dist < 1000){
  
  x = st_distance(df_sf) %>% as_tibble()
  colnames(x)= df_sf$ID
  
  # Getting the pair of closest poiunt
  x= x %>%  mutate(id0 = df_sf$ID) %>% 
    pivot_longer(cols = -id0 , names_to= "id1", values_to = "dist") %>%
    mutate(id1 = as.numeric(id1)) %>% 
    filter(dist!=0) %>% 
    slice_min(dist, with_ties = FALSE)
  
  # Extracting the distance for the WHILE criterion
  min_dist = x$dist
  
  # Getting the biggest ID to remove
  x_remove = max(x$id0, x$id1)
  
 # Removing the ID. The IF statement might be usefull to avoid an extra removal
  if(min_dist < 1000) {
    df_sf = df_sf %>% filter(ID != x_remove)
  }
  
}

# Plot (with buffer)
df_sf %>% st_buffer( dist = 500)  %>% 
  ggplot()  + geom_sf()+ geom_sf(data= df_sf) +
  geom_sf_text( aes(label= ID))

Previous attempt : this solution won't work if there is 3 or more points nearby. Ex. Point B could be selected from circle C; and A and B would be too close.
Here is a solution with sf and tidyverse. I created circles around each points (radius of 500 m ). For each circles, I checked which points (index) are inside this cricle, and took the minimal ID. After removing duplicated values, I selected the points corresponding to those indexes.
library(sf)
library(tidyverse)

x <- c(611547.6411, 589547.6411, 611447.6411, 609847.6411, 606347.6411, 611447.6411, 613547.6411,642747.6411, 589647.6411, 606447.6411, 613547.6411, 640347.6411, 642847.6411, 612147.6411, 613847.6411, 640247.6411, 642947.6411, 584347.6411, 587747.6411, 606447.6411, 614247.6411, 640447.6411, 642747.6411, 584447.6411, 608647.6411, 612047.6411, 612747.6411,
       613847.6411, 643147.6411, 583147.6411, 608747.6411, 611847.6411, 609647.6411, 610047.6411, 613747.6411, 586247.6411, 588647.6411, 643147.6411, 584347.6411, 606447.6411, 610147.6411, 613347.6411, 614647.6411, 586047.6411, 587247.6411, 611547.6411, 640347.6411, 643147.6411, 587147.6411, 583047.6411, 608747.6411, 612047.6411, 613947.6411, 587647.6411, 588547.6411, 586847.6411, 611247.6411, 643247.6411, 587247.6411, 590347.6411, 582947.6411, 608947.6411, 611847.6411, 613447.6411, 614647.6411, 585147.6411, 587647.6411, 588547.6411, 586947.6411, 611247.6411, 643047.6411, 587147.6411, 583947.6411, 587747.6411, 608547.6411, 611747.6411, 614047.6411, 585247.6411, 586247.6411, 588447.6411, 589147.6411, 611347.6411, 642447.6411, 586947.6411, 585847.6411, 587747.6411, 581447.6411, 612447.6411, 611947.6411, 600547.6411,
       612047.6411, 610347.6411, 614147.6411, 582847.6411, 588547.6411, 589247.6411, 611247.6411, 638147.6411, 640547.6411, 642947.6411, 587047.6411, 585947.6411, 587647.6411, 600447.6411, 611347.6411, 612347.6411, 610347.6411, 587747.6411, 579747.6411, 583847.6411, 586847.6411, 588447.6411, 589347.6411, 643347.6411, 589347.6411, 586947.6411, 588247.6411, 588847.6411, 585847.6411, 590847.6411, 589447.6411, 590947.6411, 581347.6411, 611847.6411, 600647.6411, 610347.6411, 615947.6411, 613947.6411, 586347.6411, 579647.6411, 584047.6411, 586347.6411, 587747.6411, 587947.6411, 586547.6411, 587647.6411, 614047.6411, 643047.6411, 587947.6411, 585747.6411, 584947.6411, 600547.6411, 611947.6411, 606847.6411, 600847.6411, 612847.6411, 615747.6411, 620747.6411, 614047.6411, 632947.6411, 588147.6411, 579747.6411, 582747.6411)

y <- c(5272140.5728, 5271740.5728, 5271640.5728, 5267440.5728, 5271540.5728, 5272040.5728, 5272340.5728, 5268540.5728, 5271240.5728, 5271640.5728, 5272140.5728, 5272240.5728, 5272240.5728, 5277940.5728, 5278040.5728, 5278040.5728, 5266940.5728, 5267040.5728, 5267440.5728, 5268140.5728, 5268640.5728, 5271140.5728, 5271740.5728, 5271740.5728, 5271940.5728, 5272140.5728, 5272240.5728, 5272040.5728, 5272140.5728, 5272140.5728, 5272140.5728, 5272240.5728, 5272340.5728, 5277240.5728, 5278040.5728, 5268540.5728, 5271240.5728, 5271340.5728, 5272240.5728, 5271940.5728, 5271940.5728, 5272040.5728, 5272040.5728, 5272040.5728, 5272040.5728, 5272040.5728, 5272140.5728, 5272140.5728,
       5272140.5728, 5272240.5728, 5272240.5728, 5277240.5728, 5278040.5728, 5278140.5728, 5278140.5728, 5265540.5728, 5266840.5728, 5266940.5728, 5267040.5728, 5268540.5728, 5272240.5728, 5272340.5728, 5272040.5728, 5272040.5728, 5277340.5728, 5278140.5728, 5278140.5728, 5265640.5728, 5266840.5728, 5267240.5728, 5268440.5728, 5271540.5728, 5272140.5728, 5271840.5728, 5271940.5728, 5271940.5728, 5271940.5728, 5272040.5728, 5272040.5728, 5272140.5728, 5272140.5728, 5272140.5728, 5272340.5728, 5277140.5728, 5277240.5728, 5277340.5728, 5277740.5728, 5277740.5728, 5278040.5728, 5278140.5728, 5278140.5728, 5278240.5728, 5278240.5728, 5264940.5728, 5265040.5728, 5265140.5728, 5266740.5728, 5266840.5728, 5266940.5728, 5267040.5728, 5267140.5728, 5267340.5728, 5267440.5728, 5268340.5728,
       5271240.5728, 5271840.5728, 5271940.5728, 5272040.5728, 5272040.5728, 5272340.5728, 5271840.5728, 5271840.5728, 5272140.5728, 5272140.5728, 5272240.5728, 5272240.5728, 5272340.5728, 5274340.5728, 5274440.5728, 5274640.5728, 5285140.5728, 5285240.5728, 5277340.5728, 5277540.5728, 5277840.5728, 5278040.5728, 5278040.5728, 5278140.5728, 5278140.5728, 5265540.5728, 5265640.5728, 5266740.5728, 5266740.5728, 5266940.5728, 5268340.5728, 5268440.5728, 5271440.5728, 5271540.5728, 5271540.5728, 5271740.5728, 5272040.5728, 5272340.5728, 5271740.5728, 5272240.5728, 5272240.5728, 5274540.5728, 5275040.5728, 5275340.5728, 5284840.5728, 5284940.5728, 5284940.5728, 5285040.5728, 5285040.5728)

coordinates.df <- as.data.frame(cbind(x,y))

# add an ID column that might be helpful and rearrange the columns
coordinates.df$ID <- 1:nrow(coordinates.df)
coordinates.df <- coordinates.df[c(3,1:2)]

# Making a sf object
df_sf = coordinates.df %>% st_as_sf(coords=c("x","y"), remove= FALSE)# %>% 

# Creating n polygons (circle) around each point, 
# checking which circles intercepts, and keeping the first value (minimum ID).
index_to_keep = st_intersects(
  df_sf %>% st_buffer( dist = 500),
                              df_sf, sparse=TRUE )  %>%
  map(min) %>% unlist() %>% 
  # Removing duplicates
  unique()

# Selecting the index with only one point
df_sf2 =  df_sf[index_to_keep, ]

# Graphical
df_sf %>% st_buffer( dist = 500)  %>% 
  ggplot()  + geom_sf()+ geom_sf(data= df_sf2)


Thank you so much VinceGreg, that goes absolutely in the desired direction. There is one thing I am wondering about. The plot at the end shows that there are still some circles overlapping. I will add the plot in the question above so it is visible.

@climsaver  Yes ,  I missed something, you are right.  I will edit my answer to mention that it don't work properly. I think that it is when 3 or more points are nearby.
However, for your last graphical verification, you need to put a radius of 250 m and check if there is no overlaps ( or keep 500m and check if no points are in two circles)

@climsaver, I made a second attempt. An other way could be to use clusters, so multiple points could be represented as the average of each location.

VinceGreg, thanks a lot for all your efforts and the improvements of your original solution. I transfered the approach (the second attempt) to my actual data set and it also works with that. It seems to do exactly what it was supposed to do.

I like the approach of VinceGreg (+1). The solution below keeps 91 point locations on a 1st pass, then reduces to 86 on a 2nd pass.
To illustrate, run this with walk(1:1, sift) (i.e. 1 pass) and you'll see in the "zoomed in" plot that location 31 escapes the net. Run again with walk(1:2, sift) (two passes) and location 31 turns red (i.e. to be discarded).
(Assumes circles can overlap provided, for example, point location 1 is not with the buffered circle of location 2.)
library(sf)
library(tidyverse)

x <- c(
  611547.6411, 589547.6411, 611447.6411, 609847.6411, 606347.6411, 611447.6411, 613547.6411,642747.6411, 589647.6411, 606447.6411, 613547.6411, 640347.6411, 642847.6411, 612147.6411, 613847.6411, 640247.6411, 642947.6411, 584347.6411, 587747.6411, 606447.6411, 614247.6411, 640447.6411, 642747.6411, 584447.6411, 608647.6411, 612047.6411, 612747.6411,
  613847.6411, 643147.6411, 583147.6411, 608747.6411, 611847.6411, 609647.6411, 610047.6411, 613747.6411, 586247.6411, 588647.6411, 643147.6411, 584347.6411, 606447.6411, 610147.6411, 613347.6411, 614647.6411, 586047.6411, 587247.6411, 611547.6411, 640347.6411, 643147.6411, 587147.6411, 583047.6411, 608747.6411, 612047.6411, 613947.6411, 587647.6411, 588547.6411, 586847.6411, 611247.6411, 643247.6411, 587247.6411, 590347.6411, 582947.6411, 608947.6411, 611847.6411, 613447.6411, 614647.6411, 585147.6411, 587647.6411, 588547.6411, 586947.6411, 611247.6411, 643047.6411, 587147.6411, 583947.6411, 587747.6411, 608547.6411, 611747.6411, 614047.6411, 585247.6411, 586247.6411, 588447.6411, 589147.6411, 611347.6411, 642447.6411, 586947.6411, 585847.6411, 587747.6411, 581447.6411, 612447.6411, 611947.6411, 600547.6411,
  612047.6411, 610347.6411, 614147.6411, 582847.6411, 588547.6411, 589247.6411, 611247.6411, 638147.6411, 640547.6411, 642947.6411, 587047.6411, 585947.6411, 587647.6411, 600447.6411, 611347.6411, 612347.6411, 610347.6411, 587747.6411, 579747.6411, 583847.6411, 586847.6411, 588447.6411, 589347.6411, 643347.6411, 589347.6411, 586947.6411, 588247.6411, 588847.6411, 585847.6411, 590847.6411, 589447.6411, 590947.6411, 581347.6411, 611847.6411, 600647.6411, 610347.6411, 615947.6411, 613947.6411, 586347.6411, 579647.6411, 584047.6411, 586347.6411, 587747.6411, 587947.6411, 586547.6411, 587647.6411, 614047.6411, 643047.6411, 587947.6411, 585747.6411, 584947.6411, 600547.6411, 611947.6411, 606847.6411, 600847.6411, 612847.6411, 615747.6411, 620747.6411, 614047.6411, 632947.6411, 588147.6411, 579747.6411, 582747.6411
  )

y <- c(
  5272140.5728, 5271740.5728, 5271640.5728, 5267440.5728, 5271540.5728, 5272040.5728, 5272340.5728, 5268540.5728, 5271240.5728, 5271640.5728, 5272140.5728, 5272240.5728, 5272240.5728, 5277940.5728, 5278040.5728, 5278040.5728, 5266940.5728, 5267040.5728, 5267440.5728, 5268140.5728, 5268640.5728, 5271140.5728, 5271740.5728, 5271740.5728, 5271940.5728, 5272140.5728, 5272240.5728, 5272040.5728, 5272140.5728, 5272140.5728, 5272140.5728, 5272240.5728, 5272340.5728, 5277240.5728, 5278040.5728, 5268540.5728, 5271240.5728, 5271340.5728, 5272240.5728, 5271940.5728, 5271940.5728, 5272040.5728, 5272040.5728, 5272040.5728, 5272040.5728, 5272040.5728, 5272140.5728, 5272140.5728,
  5272140.5728, 5272240.5728, 5272240.5728, 5277240.5728, 5278040.5728, 5278140.5728, 5278140.5728, 5265540.5728, 5266840.5728, 5266940.5728, 5267040.5728, 5268540.5728, 5272240.5728, 5272340.5728, 5272040.5728, 5272040.5728, 5277340.5728, 5278140.5728, 5278140.5728, 5265640.5728, 5266840.5728, 5267240.5728, 5268440.5728, 5271540.5728, 5272140.5728, 5271840.5728, 5271940.5728, 5271940.5728, 5271940.5728, 5272040.5728, 5272040.5728, 5272140.5728, 5272140.5728, 5272140.5728, 5272340.5728, 5277140.5728, 5277240.5728, 5277340.5728, 5277740.5728, 5277740.5728, 5278040.5728, 5278140.5728, 5278140.5728, 5278240.5728, 5278240.5728, 5264940.5728, 5265040.5728, 5265140.5728, 5266740.5728, 5266840.5728, 5266940.5728, 5267040.5728, 5267140.5728, 5267340.5728, 5267440.5728, 5268340.5728,
  5271240.5728, 5271840.5728, 5271940.5728, 5272040.5728, 5272040.5728, 5272340.5728, 5271840.5728, 5271840.5728, 5272140.5728, 5272140.5728, 5272240.5728, 5272240.5728, 5272340.5728, 5274340.5728, 5274440.5728, 5274640.5728, 5285140.5728, 5285240.5728, 5277340.5728, 5277540.5728, 5277840.5728, 5278040.5728, 5278040.5728, 5278140.5728, 5278140.5728, 5265540.5728, 5265640.5728, 5266740.5728, 5266740.5728, 5266940.5728, 5268340.5728, 5268440.5728, 5271440.5728, 5271540.5728, 5271540.5728, 5271740.5728, 5272040.5728, 5272340.5728, 5271740.5728, 5272240.5728, 5272240.5728, 5274540.5728, 5275040.5728, 5275340.5728, 5284840.5728, 5284940.5728, 5284940.5728, 5285040.5728, 5285040.5728
  )

point_df <- data.frame(x, y) |> 
  mutate(ID = row_number()) |> 
  st_as_sf(coords = c("x", "y"), remove = F)

circle_df <- point_df |> st_buffer(dist = 500)

keep <- row_number(point_df) # start with everything

sift <- \(x){
  keep <<- st_intersection(circle_df[keep, ], point_df[keep, ]) |>
    as_tibble() |>
    summarise(
      intersects = str_flatten_comma(ID.1) |> str_unique() |> str_extract("^\\d{1,3}"),
      .by = ID
    ) |>
    distinct(intersects) |>
    pull()
}

walk(1:2, sift) # 1st pass reduces to 91, 2nd pass to 86

(p <- circle_df[keep, ] |> 
  ggplot() +
  geom_sf(fill = "grey80", alpha = 0.4) +
  geom_sf(data = point_df, colour = "red", size = 1) +
  geom_sf(data = point_df[keep, ], colour = "black", size = 1))



# Zoom in and view ID 31 after 1 pass, then after 2
p + 
  geom_text(aes(x, y, label = ID), size = 3, nudge_y = 50, data = point_df) + 
  coord_sf(xlim = c(608000, 611000), ylim = c(5271000, 5273000))


Created on 2024-04-16 with reprex v2.1.0

Thanks a lot Carl for your solution and contribution. Visualizing overlaps with red color definitely makes it clearer. The solution by VinceGreg just seems more straightforward and comprehensible.

No worries. It was a fun challenge.
